# Django pre/post-save signals which invoke requests causing 502 Bad Gateweay

Tags: django, signals

My client has a Django site which uses a Page model to hold content for static pages. They want a system which saves a PDF of the page before and after any changes they make to a Page. (btw, I'm using NGINX, Supervisor, Gunicorn, Django)

To implement this, I'm using Django pre_ and post_save signal handlers which call [pdfcrowd](https://github.com/pdfcrowd/pdfcrowd-python) to save a "screenshot" of a static page before and after any time an instance of the Page model is saved. My pre-save code is as follows.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Page)
def page_pre_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    url = "%s%s" % (settings.DOMAIN, reverse(instance.name))
    fname = '%s_before' % instance.name
    fetch_pdf(url, fname)
```

Where the fetch_pdf function sends a url to pdfcrowd and saves the resulting pdf, and the post_save method is practically identical. When I update a Page model through the admin interface, the PDFs returned are 502 errors, and the admin goes to a 502 as well. If I comment off the fetch_pdf() call and manually use PDF crowd on the urls before and after updating a Page object, it works fine. Also, if I use a different domain in the page_pre_save_handler (for example, our production domain instead of the development one I'm working on) it also works fine.

In my NGINX server logs, I find the line

```
upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 69.164.218.62
```

where 69.164.218.62 is pdfcrowd.com. I've raised my timeout factors to make sure that they weren't causing this. They weren't.

In my Gunicorn logs I found:

```
2014-02-12 18:01:47 [7078] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7083)
2014-02-12 18:01:47 [7078] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7083)
2014-02-12 18:01:47 [7118] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7118
```

I've got 3 gunicorn workers and I've started the gunicorn process with a high --timeout option.

So I'm thinking the problem has something to do with the fact that I'm inducing another request which accesses the object which is being updated, but even that doesn't make much sense if the pre and post save calls actually do occur before and after the save. So I'm stumped. Any thoughts at all would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: seems like an appropriate task for celery

Comment: Possibly... i've never used celery before, but it seems like since it's asynchronous that the pre-save "screenshot" wouldn't necessarily happen before the Page gets saved. Would there be a way within Celery to guarantee that it happened first?

Comment: no but arguable that is a very bad idea to guarantee that the task will complete before save is complete. image if the api will take an hour to respond, that will be very slow for you to add any records. I think the better approach is to make those fields optional. then save the model without them and let celery fill them in at a later time. meanwhile while they can be empty, test for that in your template and possibly display something else...